# Prove that $a_{n+1} = a_n^2 - a_n+1$ for all $n$ large enough

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, inequality

> Prove that if $a_1,a_2,\ldots$ are positive integers so that $a_{n+1}\ge \prod_{k=1}^n a_k$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{a_n}$ is rational, $a_{n+1} = a_n^2 - a_n+1$ for all sufficiently large $n$.

I don't have a concrete idea of what to do; maybe a proof by contradiction could work? Would solving the following simpler problem be of any use: given $a_1 = 2, a_{n+1} = a_n^2 - a_n+1, n>0$, prove that if $m\neq n, a_m$ and $a_n$ are coprime and $\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{a_i} = 1$.

The difficulty with this problem is that I'm not sure how I can make use of the given conditions.

Comment: so, dude, where did you get the problem?

Comment: So this is not clear. Are you proving the recursion or irrationality of the resulting sum?

Comment: The product condition suggests to me that you might be best off looking at the partial sums $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{a_k}$ as rational numbers $p_n/q_n$, in lowest terms. The product condition tells me that $q_n$ is going to have to increase.

Comment: @WillJagy are you asking the source of the problem, or where the asker is having a trouble in solving the problem?

Comment: @DevanshBhardwaj I think the idea is that if the source is, say, an exercise, then at least it means that the problem has a solution. On the other hand, if the problem comes up as a research question, then it might be very difficult to solve.

Comment: @DevanshBhardwaj  the source of the problem. It may be very difficult; the OP  may have changed or left out  conditions in the original statement.  People look at "long-listed" or "short-listed"  questions submitted to contests;  sometimes these were not used in the actual contest because they turn out to need very deep machinery, or they are just false.  People love to hide their identities; they really should, however, indicate where they got the problem

Comment: For my part, I do not seem to know how to prove that the sequence $2, 2, 4, 16, 256, 65536, 4294967296,...$ has reciprocal sum   irrational.

Answer (score 6):

This exact problem is a theorem proved by Erdos and Straus back in 1963 in a paper called: On the irrationality of certain Ahmes series. I'm having some trouble finding a copy of the original paper online, so here is a [paper by Badea](https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/S0017089500006868) which starts with their theorem and then expands on it.

---

EDIT: Thank you @Will_Jagy for finding a copy of the original [Erdos/Straus paper](https://www.renyi.hu/%7Ep_erdos/1964-19.pdf).

Comment: https://www.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/1964-19.pdf

Answer (score 4):

This is only a partial solution, of the "simpler problem" (and it's simple, indeed): Let $a_1=2$ and $a_{n+1}=a_n^2-a_n+1$ for $n\ge1$. Then,
$$a_{n+1}-1=a_n\,(a_n-1)\tag{1}.$$ From this, we can show by induction that
$$a_{n+1}-1=(a_1-1)\prod^n_{m=1}a_m\tag{2}.$$ So $a_m$ is a divisor of $a_{n+1}-1$ for $m\le n$, i.e. $a_{n+1}$ and $a_m$ are coprime. Moreover, (1) can be witten as
$$\frac1{a_n}=\frac1{a_n-1}-\frac1{a_{n+1}-1},$$ so we have the telescoping series
$$\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac1{a_n}=\frac1{a_1-1}=1.$$
The original question does not seem to be entirely hopeless, considering some expansions studied by Waclaw Sierpinski.

EDIT: there is some sort of expansion related (but, alas, not identical) to the problem at hand. Let's assume we have some real, positive value $x=x_0$, and let's define $a_k$ as the least positive integer so that $1/a_k<x_k$, and $x_{k+1}=x_k-1/a_k$. Since we always have $x_n>0$ (a not so greedy algorithm), this is always an infinite process, but still, $$x=\sum^\infty_{k=0}\frac1{a_k}.$$ Due to the minimality of $a_k$, we have
$$\frac1{a_k}<x_k\le\frac1{a_k-1},$$ and thus
$$0<x_k-\frac1{a_k}=x_{k+1}\le\frac1{a_k\,(a_k-1)}.$$ This implies $$a_{k+1}>a_k\,(a_k-1)\tag{3}.$$ It's easy to see that (3) makes the expansion
$$x=\sum^\infty_{k=0}\frac1{a_k}$$ unique. And, lo and behold, $x$ is rational *if and only if* $a_{k+1}=a^2_k-a_k+1$ for $k\ge K$: if that's so, according to the above, $$\sum^\infty_{k=K}\frac1{a_k}=\frac1{a_K-1}$$ is rational, and so is
$$\sum^{K-1}_{k=0}\frac1{a_k}+\frac1{a_K-1}.$$ On the other hand, if $x_k=m/n$ is rational and a reduced fraction, it's clear that $n=m\,q-r$ with $0<r<m$, meaning $$x_{k+1}=\frac{m}{n}-\frac1{a_k}=\frac{m}{n}-\frac1q=\frac{r}{n\,q}.$$ Even if this is a reduced fraction as well (in reality, cancelations occur), $r<m$, so we'll inevitably arrive at some $x_k=1/d$. And then, $a_k=d+1$, $$x_{k+1}=\frac1{d\,(d+1)}=\frac1{a_k\,(a_k-1)}$$ and thus $a_{k+1}=a_k\,(a_k-1)+1$, and so on.

Comment: @Will Jagy The sum of the reciprocals of 2,2,4,16,256,65536,4294967296,...(each term the product of all preceding) is quite obviously irrational, because its binary expansion is not periodic.